# How to add SPBuiltInFieldId.LinkFilenameNoMenu to library view

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, powershell, list-view

I am needing to add the LinkFilenameNoMenu ("Name(linked to document with edit menu") column to a view within a library on multiple SharePoint sites. This is what I have:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell

$InvFile="ProjectURLs2.csv" 
# Get Data from Inventory CSV File 
$FileExists = (Test-Path $InvFile -PathType Leaf) 
if ($FileExists) { 
   "Loading $InvFile for processing..." 
   $tblData = import-csv $InvFile 
} else { 
   "$InvFile not found - stopping import!" 
  exit 
}

foreach ($row in $tblData)
{
$ProjectURL = $row."ProjectURL".ToString()

$web = Get-SPWeb "$ProjectURL"

$list = $web.Lists["Document Library"]

$View = $List.Views["All Documents without Folders"]

$field = $List.Fields["SPBuiltInFieldId.LinkFilenameNoMenu"]


$View.ViewFields.Add($field)


$view.Update()

}
```

I am getting

> "Exception calling "Add" with "1" arguments(S): "Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object"" on the line for
>   "$View.ViewFields.Add($field).

Any thoughts on how I should modify this so that I can add this column to my library views?

Answer (score 3):

This **error** usually occurs in case the provided `FieldName` is not correct.

**So In your script, try to do the following:**

- Remove this line `$field = $List.Fields["SPBuiltInFieldId.LinkFilenameNoMenu"]`.
- Provide the column name directly at `$View.ViewFields.Add($field)` as the following:

  - The field name for `Name (linked to document with edit menu)` is **`LinkFilename`**
  - The field name for `Name (linked to document)` is **`LinkFilenameNoMenu`**

So based on the corresponding column name, it should look like this

```
$View.ViewFields.Add("LinkFilenameNoMenu") #LinkFilenameNoMenu
```

**The final script**

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell

$InvFile="ProjectURLs2.csv" 
# Get Data from Inventory CSV File 
$FileExists = (Test-Path $InvFile -PathType Leaf) 
if ($FileExists) { 
   "Loading $InvFile for processing..." 
   $tblData = import-csv $InvFile 
} else { 
   "$InvFile not found - stopping import!" 
  exit 
}

foreach ($row in $tblData)
{
$ProjectURL = $row."ProjectURL".ToString()
$web = Get-SPWeb "$ProjectURL"
$list = $web.Lists["Document Library"]
$View = $List.Views["All Documents without Folders"]
$View.ViewFields.Add("LinkFilenameNoMenu")
$view.Update()
}
```